# how to define multiple elements in template attribute of custom directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Below is my sample.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('search', function() {
      return {

        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
       template :'<div>
                  Email <input type = "text"> 
                  Password <input type = "text">
                  <input type = "submit"></div>'

              };
});
```

I am getting below error

```
Template must have exactly one root element. was: <h3>Hello World!!</h3> <h1>Hiii World!!</h1>
```

please suggest me how to define multiple elements using template attribute not using templateurl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception itself says that the Template must need one root element

Try this

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SJ63J/)**

```
app.directive('search', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
       template :'<div>\
                  Email <input type = "text"> \
                  Password <input type = "text">\
                  <input type = "submit"></div>'
    };
});
```